# Show that the functor $H_0 :$ R-Ch $\to$ R-Mod is neither left nor right adjoint to $i:$ R-Mod $\to$ R-Ch

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring.

Consider the inclusion functor $i:$ R-Mod $\to$ R-Ch and the functor $H_0 :$ R-Ch $\to$ R-Mod  where $R$-Mod is the category of left $R$- modules, and $R-Ch$ the category of chain complexes of left $R$-modules

How do I show that $H_0$ is neither left nor right adjoint to $i$? I am new to chain complexes and I having trouble manipulating them in the definition of adjoint pair.

Comment: Use definition. Functors $L,R$ form an adjoint pair when $\operatorname{Hom}(LX,Y)\cong \operatorname{Hom}(X,RY)$. In your case, you can show that there is no such isomorphism.

Comment: This is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4804240/1179406.

Comment: @Ennar I was trying to do that, but I don't know what should fail,  Plenty of options for something not being and isomorphism. I thought I had to use some preservation property of adjointness instead

Comment: Let me give you an example when $L$ is the inclusion and $R = H_0$. Then, $\operatorname{Hom}(LX, Y) = \{ f\colon X\to Y_0 \mid d_0f = 0 \}$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(X,RY) = \{ f\colon X\to \ker d_0/\operatorname{im} d_1\}.$ These would obviously be the same if $\operatorname{im} d_1$ were always trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the inclusion $i$ for *general* (perhaps unbounded!) chain complexes, $\mathsf{RMod}\to\mathsf{Ch(\mathsf{RMod})}$.

Exercise: show $i$ is in fact left adjoint to the zero-cycle functor $Z_0:\mathsf{Ch(\mathsf{RMod})}\to\mathsf{RMod}$.

Exercise $(2)$: show $i$ is right adjoint to the functor $C\mapsto C_0/B_0$.

So, in the left or the right directions, you know what the adjoints of $i$ must look like.

Exercise $(3)$: convince yourself $H_0$ is not isomorphic to either of these. Why does that suffice to answer your question?

Finding adjoints of $i$ is definitely overkill here. But, it's fun :)

This is like a free-forgetful-cofree situation but in the "wrong" direction. A question I'd like to know the answer to is: does the adjunction chain extend in either direction?

Comment: Apart from the slight change of notation, isn't $Z_0$ the same as my $H_0$? and so your propose exercises is telling to prove the opposite of my statement?

Comment: @darkside, no, homology is cycles quotiented by boundaries.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)#Construction_of_homology_groups), for example. You can actually take a look at my second comment underneath your question and compare it to this answer.

Comment: I haven't been introduced to $Z_0$. Is the distinction in the definition of how the functor acts on morphisms and is that supposed to be implicit in the notation given that the definition is not given? Because both $Z_0$ and $H_0$ go from chain complexes to modules, so behave the same on objects

Comment: @darkside, well, I gave you a link that you can read. This situation demonstrates that it would be helpful if you included any context whatsoever in your question, what definitions you know, what you tried etc.

Comment: @darkside "Because both $Z_0$ and $H_0$ go from chain complexes to modules, so behave the same on objects" is really, really, wrong. It's like saying for any two sets $X,Y$, all functions $X\to Y$ are the same. This is almost never true. Having the same domain and codomain category really does not say anything about what the functor does on objects, it merely tells you what "kind" of object these functors deal with. $Z_0$ is **not** $H_0$. $Z_0$ is also just notation. If you've been told what homology is, then somewhere in your head or your notes you know what cycles ($Z_\bullet$) are

Comment: @Ennar Do you know whether or not $\mathsf{eval}_0\dashv i\dashv Z_0$ extends in either direction?

Comment: @FShrike I see your point, but I didn't mean that. Of course domain and codomain are not being enough, but the way I understood the definition of functor is as composed of 4 things it maps one category to another and this is what I call the action on objects and it maps morphism to morphisms and there is the compatibility with composition and the identity. And my point was that you just stated the first of them, while the second I assume is implicit by saying that is called zero-cycle

Comment: @FShrike not from top of my head, but I'll try and think about it.

Comment: @darkside there is an implicit definition of $Z_0$ on arrows, yes. It is a kernel after all. It’s still false that they ‘behave the same on objects’; there are many examples of complexes whose $Z_0$ object is not isomorphic to their $H_0$ object. But that’s kinda the point of my hints/“exercises”.

Comment: @FShrike though, I don't see why $\mathsf{eval}_0\dashv i$. Take chain complex $C$ to be $0\to R\stackrel{\mathrm{id}_R}{\to} R\to 0$ where $d_1 = \mathrm{id}_R$, and take $M$ to be $R$. Then, $\mathrm{id}_R\colon C_0 \to M$ doesn't extend to map of chain complexes $C\to i(M)$ because $\mathrm{id}_R\circ d_1 \neq 0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FShrike, to be more precise, what's the unit $\eta_C\colon C \to i(\mathsf{eval}_0C)$?

Comment: @Ennar you’re quite right, I screwed up. I should have written it out instead of doing sloppy mental maths. The left adjoint is actually going to be $C/B_0$.

Comment: @FShrike, that makes more sense, yes. That should work due to universal property of cokernel, just like $i\dashv Z_0$ works due to universal property of kernel.

Comment: @FShrike Since finding the adjoint is overkill, is there a shorter way?

Comment: @darkside The easiest ways to do this that I can see will implicitly use the fact that instead of $H_0$ the 'correct' object is $Z_0$ or $C_0/B_0$ so, it's not very overkill. What I meant was, in general you couldn't expect $i$ to have adjoints at all, but here the fact that it does makes things cleaner

Comment: @FShrike Trying to answer the question after exercise 3: This answers the question because adjoint functors are unique up to natural isomorphism? If yes, why precisely?

Comment: @darkside That's right. Say $L$ and $L'$ are both left adjoints to $R:D\to C$. We know $D(Lx,y)\cong C(x,Ry)\cong D(L'x,y)$ naturally in $x,y$. By fixing $x$ and looking at $y$, it follows that $Lx\cong L'x$ be the Yoneda lemma. Because these isomorphisms were also natural in $x$, you can check without too much difficulty that the $Lx\cong L'x$ are also natural i.e. $L\cong L'$ as a natural isomorphism of functors. Alternatively, you get the iso. $Lx\to L'x$ as the $L\dashv R$-transpose of the $L'\dashv R$-unit $x\to RL'x$

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, this can easily be proven if you write down definition of adjoint pair of functors. First let's check $i\dashv H_0$. We would need to have $$\DeclareMathOperator{Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}} \Hom_{R\,\rm{Ch}}(i(X),Y)\cong \Hom_{R\,\rm{Mod}}(X,H_0(Y))\tag{1}$$

For the LHS hom, let's look at the following diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
@>>> 0 @>>> X @>>> 0 @>>>\\
@. @VVV @VV f V   @VVV \\
@>>> Y_1 @>>d_1> Y_0 @>>d_0> Y_{-1} @>>>
\end{CD}

We need squares to commute which is equivalent to writing $d_0\circ f = 0$, so $$\Hom_{R\,\rm{Ch}}(i(X),Y)\cong \{f\in\Hom_{R\,\rm{Mod}}(X,Y_0)\mid d_0\circ f = 0\} \cong \Hom_{R\,\rm{Mod}}(X,\ker d_0)\tag{2}$$ where the second isomorphism is due to universal property of kernel.

Meanwhile, just from definition of homology we have $$\Hom_{R\,\rm{Mod}}(X,H_0(Y))\cong \Hom_{R\,\rm{Mod}}(X,\ker d_0/\operatorname{im} d_1).\tag{3}$$

From this it's clear that $(1)$ holds whenever $\operatorname{im}d_1$ is trivial, so for counterexample we need chain complex $Y$ with non-trivial $d_1$.

So, let $X = R$ and $Y$ chain complex with $d_1 = {\rm{id}}_R$, with all other differentials $0$. Then, from $(1)$ we have $\Hom_{R\,\rm{Ch}}(i(X),Y)\cong \operatorname{End}_R(R)$ and from $(2)$ we have $\Hom_{R\,\rm{Mod}}(X,H_0(Y)) \cong 0$.

This shows that $H_0$ is not right adjoint to the inclusion $i$. From $(2)$ it's clear that the right adjoint to $i$ is actually functor $Z_0$, (see [Construction of homology groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)#Construction_of_homology_groups)).

To show that $H_0$ is not left adjoint to the inclusion $i$, you can pretty much do the same calculations and use (almost) the same counterexample (just shift the chain complex $\ldots\to 0\to R \stackrel{{\rm{id}}_R}{\to} R\to 0\to\ldots$ appropriately).